# The video sequence editor doesn't make a sound when I put it on the play bar

Tags: video-sequence-editor

https://youtu.be/iLvapqyGeTU?t=696

In this tutorial video, the sound comes out when the YouTuber presses the playbar, but I don't.
When I press play, it makes a sound.
I moved the bar so it wouldn't make any noise.

[image]

Comment: i do not understand what you want...!? if i start the animation, i can hear a sound...if you mean that.

Comment: If you look at the YouTube link, it makes a sound when youtuber moves the playbar.
The sound is not clean because it moves the playbar and makes a sound.
When I play, it makes a sound, but I don't want to press the play and just move the play bar. it makes sounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

it's audio scrubbing.
you can find it in timeline.